# How to pass images in bootstrap modal that encoded and stored in the database as json array

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am new to laravel .I have inserted multiple images in database as an array by encoding json

```
if($request->hasfile('image'))
  {

     foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
     {
         $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
         $image->move('images/formuploads/', $name);  
         $data[] = $name;  
     }
  }

  $upload= new classified_sales();
  $upload->image=json_encode($data);
  $upload->save();
```

}

I have following code for insert data,how I could get this array of images to show them on bootstrap modal?
How should I get source of image here?

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary saleflat-edit" id="flat_sale"
    data-product="{{$classified_sales->product}}"
    data-description="{{$classified_sales->description}}" 
    data-ownername="{{$classified_sales->ownername}}" 
    data-clf_id="{{$classified_sales->uid}}"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saleflat-edit">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply loop the data appending your images directory.

```
foreach($data as $image){ ?>
      <img src="images/formuploads/<?php echo $image ?>">      
 <? }
```

Comment: i want to pass it to modal data and images path are stored as JSON array